# tone: the sick man of . .

Tags: word-meaning, connotations

I'd like to know whether the phrase **the sick man of . . .** has a tone of ridicule to it in the following:

> Today, Europe again looks like **the sick man of** the global economy.’
>
> ‘Many is the occasion that I have lauded the economy's transformation from the dire days of the 1970s, when Britain was **the sick man of** Europe.’

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sick_man_of_Europe for the phrase in general.  It is difficult to make a convincing assessment of the tone of a particular usage of it without knowing the speaker/writer and the context, so perhaps you could add the source of that quote (or quotes?).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a hint of contempt and derision. The phrase may have been first used by J. Russell in 1853 to describe the Ottoman Empire as, "the sick man of Europe". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sick_man_of_Europe) on this.